# Arbritary intersection of open sets (Alexandroff).

Tags: general-topology

Given a set X with a preorder relation $\leq$. Given the basic open sets 
$$A_a=\{b\in X|b\leq a\} $$
Prove that the following arbritary intersection is open:
$$\bigcap_{a\in X} A_a$$

Comment: Since $A_a$ is closed, $\bigcap_{a\in X}A_a$ is closed.

Comment: Consider the set $Y=\{a\in X:\ b\leq a\implies b=a\}$. Then $\bigcap_{a\in X}A_a=\bigcup_{a\in Y}A_a$.

Comment: Could you remind us please how the topology and the given preorder relate? That intersection does not seem arbitrary to me at all.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain it as well as I could. Now you have that this topology is generated by this family of sets so as far  as my topology knowledge goes I think that this sets (and finite intersections and unions) are the only ones which that topology has.